# How to handle JSF multiple unexpected exception?

Tags: jsf, exception

I'm implementing a ExceptionHandlerFactory to handle unexpected errors in my application following the JSF 2.0 documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Handling+Server+Errors . The implementation works well for the most scenarios. However when I turn off my database, several errors occurred and the initialization generates multiple exceptions for connection like java.sql.SQLException, hibernate exceptions, bean injection exceptions, etc. The method handle() is executed multiple times also redirect to the error page multiple times. The handle code bellow:

```
public void handle() throws FacesException {

    final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context =
                (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();

        // get the exception from context
        Throwable t = context.getException();

        final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
        final NavigationHandler nav = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

        //here you do what ever you want with exception
        try {

            //log error ?
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Critical Exception!", t);

            //redirect error page
            requestMap.put("exceptionMessage", t.getMessage());
            nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/error");
            fc.renderResponse();

            // remove the comment below if you want to report the error in a jsf error message
            //JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(t.getMessage());

        } finally {
            //remove it from queue
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    //parent hanle
    getWrapped().handle();
}
```

I see over 15 request to error page in Firefox debug console.
What is the best way to prevent the multiple redirects?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed send only 1 response per request. One of the ways is to just replace `while` by `if` and remove all remaining exceptions in another `while`. The first exception is of most interest anyway. All other exceptions are merely consequences.

```
if (i.hasNext()) {
    // Original code here.
}

while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    i.remove();
}
```

You can get [inspiration](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java) from [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) of JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org).

Another way is to collect all exceptions in some list and then render one error page wherein you present that list in some iterating component accordingly (e.g. `ui:repeat` or `h:dataTable`).